# Conditional Formatting by color based on time(military time) and date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Trying to return the appropriate ticket color in Column H based on the categories listed in the colored-coded table. Currently I am using an IF(AND) statement to test just the first condition of said table of categories but it continually returns only the false value. The time column (G) is formatted as General rather than Time. I would prefer to keep times in the military format if possible. Not sure if this is the best technique to accomplish my goal or where I am going wrong in the formula. I am only testing the Red condition at this point as this is my first time messing with time calculations but eventually I will need to check against all the listed options.

Column F is the dates(formatted as a Date), Column G is the times (i.e. 1605 for 4:05 PM; formatted as General), M2 = 20-Dec-20 (formatted as a date). Row 1 is the Column categories and data starts in Row 2.

```
=IF((AND(F2=$M$2, G2<=1559)), "RED", "OTHER")
```

[Color Coded Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuewJ.png)

[Formula and Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JU6W6.png)

Back to researching Excel and time/date stuff....

UPDATE: This formula...

```
=IF(AND((G2/2400)>=(500/2400), (G2/2400)<=(1559/2400), (F2=$M$2)), "RED", "OTHER")
```

...successfully returns the right color for time and date so now for the better of my two questions; is this the best way to do this sort of calculation rather than just chaining IF statements?

```
=IF(AND((G2/2400)>=(500/2400), (G2/2400)<=(1559/2400), (F2=$M$2)), "RED", IF(AND((G2/2400)>=(500/2400), (G2/2400)<=(1559/2400), (F2=$M$3)), "BLUE", IF(AND((G2/2400)>=(500/2400), (G2/2400)<=(1559/2400), (F2=$M$4)), "WHITE", IF(AND((G2/2400)>=(500/2400), (G2/2400)<=(1559/2400), (F2=$M$5)), "YELLOW", IF(AND((G2/2400)>=(500/2400), (G2/2400)<=(1559/2400), (F2=$M$6)), "PINK", "OTHER")))))
```

Comment: you can try : https://exceljet.net/index-and-match